# Rails 4, Ajax Template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to add a simple message form with Ajax call for practice but getting an error about template is missing. Error shows that its devise (gem) related error. Error is

**Missing template messages/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * 
"/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-3.5.4/app/views"**

Code in **messeges/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Chat</h1>

<ul id="chat">
  <%= render @messages %>
</ul>

<%= form_for Message.new, remote: true do |f| %>

    <input name="authenticity_token"
           type="hidden"
           value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
    <%= f.text_field :subject, placeholder: "Subject" %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

partial view is **_message.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= message.subject %>: <%= message.content %>
</li>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#chat').append("< %=  j render(@message) %>");
$("#message_content").val('');
```

and create action in controller **messages_controller.rb** is

```
def create
    @message = Message.create!(params[:message])
     # respond_to do |format|
     #   format.html
     #   format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
     # end
 end
```

Comment: your file `create.js.html` should be called `create.js.erb`, try and let us know

Comment: sorry my mistake it is already **create.js.erb**

Comment: i don't think is a devise problem, perhaps it tries to respond with an html file while you want to run a script. To respond with js you have to write: `respond_to do |format| if @message = Message.create!(params[:message]) format.js end`

Comment: PopescuAlexandruConstantin  i chnged it as you suggested. ' 
    respond_to do |format| if @message = Message.create (params[:message]) format.js  end' now i am getting **ActionController::UnknownFormat** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `respond_to :html, :js` at the top of your controller or do as @Popescu Alexandru Constantin said:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
```

Comment: @Faian now getting error **ActionController::UnknownFormat**  after this change.

Comment: Please try my first suggestion, add `respond_to :js, :html` as the first line inside your controller. This will take care of rendering your js templates when the response headers state javascript.

Comment: thanks to getting back. I already had tried it but its not working. Any other suggestion please.

Comment: can you please try to set the `url:` option in the form_for method and also pass the format as an option to the path method.